# Trigger if certain data matches - Mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have 2 tables load_data and logs.

I have written a trigger on the `load_data` table (mysql).
The trigger inserts the data into the logs table on Updates

I would like to insert the data in "load_data" only when the 3 columns has following records

If `diIndex=3 && diMode=0 && diStatus=1` then only execute insert statement.

I tried this but throws an error

```
SELECT 1
   INTO @id
   FROM load_data
   WHERE diIndex=3 && diMode=0 && diStatus=1;

   IF @id != 1
   THEN
       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
values("83","Plant","1","Trigger")
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT @a := EXISTS ((SELECT 1 FROM load_data WHERE diIndex=3 and diMode=0 and diStatus=1));
IF @a = 1 THEN

       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
       VALUES("83","Plant","1","Trigger");

END IF;
```

or

```
IF EXISTS ((SELECT 1 FROM load_data WHERE diIndex=3 and diMode=0 and diStatus=1)) THEN
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
       VALUES("83","Plant","1","Dark Red");
END;

ELSEIF EXISTS((SELECT 1 FROM load_data WHERE diIndex=1 and diMode=0 and diStatus=1)) THEN
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
       VALUES("83","Plant","1","Yellow");
END;

ELSEIF EXISTS((SELECT 1 FROM load_data WHERE diIndex=3 and diMode=0 and diStatus=1)) THEN
BEGIN
       INSERT INTO logs(user_id,button_name,flag,box_name)
       VALUES("83","Plant","1","RED");
END;

END IF;
```

Comment: I tried it says error near End if

Comment: Ok some problem with END if it seems

Comment: Great worked like a charm :)

Comment: hey can I write Else If condition as well in the trigger IF EXISTS, ELSEIF IF EXISTS ?

Comment: I updated the answer that code doesnt work, please help

Comment: I've edited it , try now

Comment: wow man you a star!!!

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166132/show-the-matching-record-only-for-the-3-rows can you help this with please

Comment: what is the problem?, there is an accepted answer on this question